# Invalid output Tensor index: 1 when running a custom yolov3-tiny model on Google's TFLite Object Detection example

Tags: android, tensorflow, tensorflow-lite

I'm facing an error when trying to run a tiny-yolov3 model on [TensorFlow Lite's Object Detection Android Demo](https://github.com/tensorflow/examples/tree/master/lite/examples/object_detection/android).
When I try to run the app on mobile phone, the app crashed with the following error

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: inference
    Process: org.tensorflow.lite.examples.detection, PID: 5535
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid output Tensor index: 1
        at org.tensorflow.lite.NativeInterpreterWrapper.getOutputTensor(NativeInterpreterWrapper.java:292)
        at org.tensorflow.lite.NativeInterpreterWrapper.run(NativeInterpreterWrapper.java:166)
        at org.tensorflow.lite.Interpreter.runForMultipleInputsOutputs(Interpreter.java:314)
        at org.tensorflow.lite.examples.detection.tflite.TFLiteObjectDetectionAPIModel.recognizeImage(TFLiteObjectDetectionAPIModel.java:204)
        at org.tensorflow.lite.examples.detection.DetectorActivity$2.run(DetectorActivity.java:181)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
        at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:65)
```

[Here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Av7Q1mjLdOIEE81oNnt8cLENlXykxnEu/view?usp=sharing)'s my tflite and labelfile.

I changed the following on DetectorActivity.java to avoid [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61984286/cannot-convert-between-a-tensorflowlite-buffer-with-307200-bytes-and-a-java-buff) error

```
TF_OD_API_INPUT_SIZE from 300 to 416
TF_OD_API_IS_QUANTIZED from true to false
```

Then I changed the following on TFLiteObjectDetectionAPIModel.java

```
NUM_DETECTIONS from 10 to 2535
d.outputLocations = new float[1][NUM_DETECTIONS][4] to d.outputLocations = new float[1][NUM_DETECTIONS][7];
```

[Here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Zf0i2Y_Tjyh7Li3UcxteKRB_k5Bwhhgt/view?usp=sharing)'s the DetectorActivity.java and TFLiteObjectDetectionAPIModel.java that I use

[Here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1QqJTQuKwu6QVWifvuDVlr8ya5qhYUJJB/view?usp=sharing)'s my model .weight, cfg, and .pb if needed

Any assistance would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could reproduce the issue using your custom model and source code. Thanks for providing them.

The main issue is that your custom `detect.tflite` model has an output spec which is different from the one expected by the object detection example app.

You can see the difference using a model visualizer such as [netron](https://github.com/lutzroeder/netron).

The original model used by the example app (mobilenet_ssd) looks like this:

[image]

As you can see, there are 4 scalar float32 outputs, which are essentially split from the final `TFLite_Detection_PostProcess` node.

[image]

On the other hand, your model has a single output tensor in [1,2535,7] shape.

[image]

So when the app's Java code runs `tfLite.runForMultipleInputsOutputs(inputArray, outputMap)`, it tries to assign the multiple outputs based on what you put in the `outputMap`. However, because there is only one output tensor in your model, when it tries to assign the output at index 1 into `outputClasses` array, it fails with the error message.

I don't know enough details about the yolov3 model to help you with the exact command to use for converting the model, but [this doc](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/g3doc/running_on_mobile_tensorflowlite.md) should give more detailed information on how the original model was converted.

Comment: Thank you so much for the detailed answer. Do you think the problem is in the conversion method? Or do you think that yolov3-tiny is flat out unable to be used with tf-lite?

Comment: I would say you're very close to making it work. Normally, the model conversion process is the biggest hurdle, and as long as you have a working TFLite model, using it in an app should be relatively straightforward. At this point, you should either try adjusting the conversion parameters to make it match the expected output format, or modify the app code to read the output tensor of your model as is, and just extract the detected objects from the output tensor based on the yolov3-tiny model output specs.

Comment: Hey, did you ever solve this? I have a very similar problem